# Why does Mapbox GL's draw_create function fire multiple times under different closures while creating a `LineString?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl-draw

I am using [mapbox-gl-draw](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/main/docs/API.md) in a React.js app to facilitate path creation on a Mapbox canvas. Since I'm in React, I have to declare the `draw.create` event handler within a `useEffect()` block. Since my `draw.create` handler depends on a state variable, I declare the variable in the dependency list at the end of the `useEffect()` block. Here is the essence of the `useEffect()` block, with two debugging statements added to try to understand the behavior:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.dir("In useEffect to initialize draw_create...");
    /* POINT 1 */
    if (defineFeature === null) {
      console.dir("defineFeature is null");
    } else {
      console.dir("Value of defineFeature: " + defineFeature.holeNum + ", " + 
      defineFeature.featureType);
    }
           
      map.current.on('draw.create', ()=> {
        /* POINT 2 */
        if (defineFeature === null) {
          console.dir("defineFeature is null");
        } else {
          console.dir("Value of defineFeature: " + defineFeature.holeNum + ", " + 
          defineFeature.featureType);
        }
        /* Code to process the line is omitted */
  },[defineFeature]);
```

When I execute this code, the value of `defineFeature` is as expected at POINT 1; it is the most recent value of `defineFeature`. However, the value of `defineFeature` at POINT 2, within `draw_create`, is a different matter. After a user double-clicks to terminate a line_string on the map canvas, the `draw.create` handler is fired *multiple* times under different closures! The first time `draw.create`fires, `defineFeature` is `null`, which is its value when the map first initializes. The last time `draw.create` fires, the value of `defineFeature` is correct. However, at that point, it's too late; the function has already tried to process the line with an incorrect (stale) value of `defineFeature`.

The number of times that `draw.create` fires when the user double-clicks to terminate a `LineString` is not predictable. From what I can gather, it seems to depend on the number of previous closures of `draw.create`. Indeed, the value of `defineFeature` in each invocation seems to be different, aligning with its previous values.

Can anyone explain this behavior--and, more importantly, how to fix it? In `draw.create`, I need to be able to  use the value of `defineFeature` under the most recent closure.

Answer (score 0):

I need to provide a clean-up function to `useEffect()` to remove the `draw.create` handler whenever the `defineFeature` state variable changes, as recommended at the end of [this thread](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9627). Without removing the `draw.create` function each time `defineFeature` changes, we get multiple closures of `draw.create`, leading to the strange behavior I observed.

To clean up the `draw-create` function, place it in a separate function, which can reside either inside or outside the `useEffect()`. I named the function `processDrawFeature()` and I placed it at the top of the `useEffect()` block. Then, at the bottom of the `useEffect()` block, I first bound the `draw,create` handler to it:

```
 map.current.on('draw.create', processDrawnFeature);
```

Then, on the last line of the `useEffect()` block, I defined the cleanup function:

```
return () => map.current.off('draw.create', processDrawnFeature);
```

After making these changes, the `draw.create` is always bound to a closure of `processDrawnFeature` that has the most recent value of the `defineFeature` state variable. Hooray!

Comment: Can someone please accept this as the answer?